# Can Azure Functions encounter timeout exceptions?

Tags: plugins, dynamics-crm, customization

Does Azure Functions experience timeout exceptions similar to those encountered in D365 plugins or workflows?

In past experiences, I've utilized plugins for handling bulk operations, such as creating and updating over 150 quoteline products. However, I encountered timeout exceptions during certain instances, leading to incomplete operations. My goal is to ensure that such operations can run in the background seamlessly, without being affected by timeout issues.

Comment: Yes - of course! By default, consumption-based Azure Functions can run up to 5 minutes (adjustable to 10 minutes)

Comment: For my customer we designed Azure functions just for off-loading long running bulk operations. Of course these need to be asynchronous and a durable function is a good option for this purpose. Azure functions come in all sorts of configurations, hence they can run for days when needed.